# Device not configured when downloading remote PDF in ASP.NET Core

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, dotnet-httpclient

I'm trying to download a PDF from a remote URL in order to add it to a mail attachment.

My application is a .NET Core 2.1 API.  The URL is a single page PDF on AWS cloudfront.

```
    try
    {
        using (var httpClient = new HttpClient())
        {
            string url = AttachmentPath + "/" + AttachmentFilename;
            byte[] bytes = await httpClient.GetByteArrayAsync(url);
            string fileContentsAsBase64 = Convert.ToBase64String(bytes);

            msg.AddAttachment(AttachmentFilename, fileContentsAsBase64, "application/pdf");
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {

    }
```

I'm getting the following error:

> {System.Net.Sockets.SocketException (6): Device not configured    at System.Net.Http.ConnectHelper.ConnectAsync(String host, Int32 port,
>   CancellationToken cancellationToken)}

What am I doing wrong?

**Update**

Thanks to the link shared below, I've modified the code as follows:

```
private static HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient();

    try
    {
        string url = AttachmentPath + "/" + AttachmentFilename;
        // The following line causes the exception
        byte[] bytes = await httpClient.GetByteArrayAsync(url);
        string fileContentsAsBase64 = Convert.ToBase64String(bytes);

    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {

    }
```

The exception occurs at await httpClient.GetByteArrayAsync.

Comment: confirm on which line you get the error and also that the URL is valid/

Comment: Reference [You're using HttpClient wrong](https://aspnetmonsters.com/2016/08/2016-08-27-httpclientwrong/)

Comment: Provide a [mcve] that clarifies your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Thanks @Nkosi,. I've updated my question

Answer (score 0):

It seems that your S3 Config is missing. You need to include your S3 config in the HttpClient possibly mapped to header.

there is similar issue on [GitHub#1014](https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-net/issues/1014) whereas this uses `AmazonS3Client`.